# How to get rid of translation

Tags: filtering

Sorry guys for these noob question. But how do i get rid of these translations in light grey under the actual names of the functions.

[image]

Comment: Deselect Preferences->Interface->Show Code Captions  may help

Comment: thanks, problem is fixed now.